# Automatic reorganize index of database with stored procedure

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to create a stored procedure that picks out all the table names and index names that have a specific fragmentation percent, add them to a list, then loop through that list and perform my reorganisation of the indexes for each of those index.

**Pseudo**

```
@list = select * indexes
@Counter = 0

BEGIN
   WHILE Counter < list.count
      foreach index REBUILD
   END
```

Is there any elegant and easy way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is a really easy way to do this that doesn't involve re-inventing the wheel:

[Ola Hallengren - SQL Server Maintenance Solution](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html)

This is pretty much the best tool I've found for index maintenance and works so well, there's no reason to try and roll your own.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Could I then create a job that executes the EXECUTE dbo.IndexOptimize?

Comment: The tool will create all the jobs for you